# setBackgroundDrawable give nullpointerexception in android

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a circle inside a fragment and I need to change its color in runtime in future.
but the method `setBackgroundDrawable` gives me `nullPointerException`.

I am not able to figure it out as I am web developer and I am new to android development. Please help me.

And the code is below

```
   public class tester extends Fragment {
    private View circle_holder;
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.today, container, false);
        circle_holder = (View)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cicle);
        ShapeDrawable mDrawable = new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape());
        mDrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.RED);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16){
            circle_holder.setBackground(mDrawable);
        }
        else{
            circle_holder.setBackgroundDrawable(mDrawable);
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line.

```
circle_holder = (View)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.cicle);
```

into

```
circle_holder = (View)rootView .findViewById(R.id.cicle);
```

Comment: hey kalyan, thanks a lot. It worked. 
can you give me quick tip how you debugged or found out. so it will help me in future ?

Comment: hi @swati when ever you used in fragment you have to get views with using Your inflated view.findviewById or there is method called getView in fragment which will return the your inflated view but it is used after the onCreateView() is called.so with using above two methods you can the views in the fragment..

Comment: @swati getActivity.findViewById() is used to get the view of parent Activity in which your fragment is added..but most of the times it is not needed.